I am having difficulty with the Curve 5-6 Polygon calc used in the Ken Flerlage Sankey funnel template
I have leveraged the Sankey funnel template from Ken Flerlage however I needed to add an additional step (Step 6) for my use case. Everything went smoothly until we got to the Curve 5-6 visualization.
I get an error for the Curve 5-6 Polygon calc. The calc is set up like all the others:
IF ISNULL(ATTR([Step 5])) OR ATTR([Step 5])="" OR ISNULL(ATTR([Step 6])) OR ATTR([Step 6])="" THEN
    NULL
ELSE
    CASE ATTR([Min or Max])
    WHEN 'Min' THEN [Curve 5-6 Min]
    WHEN 'Max' THEN [Curve 5-6 Max]
    END
END

and the table calculation is correct as well (as I see in other tabs)  - see screenshot below.

The error I receive is "Error: The Curve 5-6 Polygon table calculation requires a field that is missing from the view as the Step 1 1 field to the view to resolve".
I added Step 1, Step 2.. all Steps to the viz and the error doesn't clear. I'm not even sure why it's asking for "Step 1 1" as that doesn't exist in the data.
When I initially drop the pill to the rows area, Step 1 and Step 2 are automatically are selected as if Tableau wants this data to be used in the calc. I tried to refresh the data, I tried recreating the calc under a different name.. nothing works. Help!!!
I tried to create a "Step 1 1" field by duplicating Step 1, but it says the "Field or logical table named "Step 1 1" already exists" Huh??? I can't find it in the data area...

Did you try the troubleshooting methods described at the bottom of the article you linked? They describe your problem almost exactly.

You might also want to look at a Tableau viz extension such as this funnel extension https://exchange.tableau.com/products/1030. Watch the exchange for new extensions over time. There are several Sankey extensions listed. Using an extension will usually be easier than the Table calc approaches that were needed prior to Tableau version 2024.2

Thanks all. @MUFF, yes I did look at the troubleshooting offered and it did provide some additional help but now I am encountering a different issue. I think I will open up a new question for that one. Thank you
